# mysql trigger : column not part of the update is not null

Tags: mysql, triggers

mysql V 5.6

Hi, I have an issue with a trigger BEFORE UPDATE : on a table, I have a flag defiend as a tinyint, not null, default value 1 . I have a before update trigger that set this flag to 1 whenever the row if updated. But, I also need in one process to explicitly set the flag to 0, so I tried that

```
create trigger t BEFORE UPDATE on table for each row
BEGIN
IF new.flag is NULL THEN  
    set new.flag = 1
 END IF;
```

Problem : **new.flag is never null.** Checking with

```
IF new.flag is NULL THEN  
    set new.flag = 1
ELSEIF new.flag = 0 THEN
    set new.flag = 3
END IF;
```

set the column to 3 whenever I update the table without including the flag in the update query. Worse, I cannot check against empty string to put the flag to 1, as a select ('' = 0) return true, if using :

```
IF new.flag is NULL OR new.flag = '' THEN  
    set new.flag = 1
END IF;
```

I can never explicitly set the flag to 0 . Shouldn't a column not part of the update be null in NEW ? What can I do, is it a mysql config to change ?

Thanks

Comment: `new` will contain the values the row will have after the update (and `old` the values before). If you don't set it in your query, it will have the value it had before (`new` is not the list of columns you used in your update query). You could use e.g. `set flag = 3` in your update-query as a marker that you want to have it set to 0 in your trigger. Or your might want to change your logic, common update markers are e.g. `timestamp` fields with `on update current_timestamp`.

Comment: @Solarflare ha, setting a fake value and then to 0 in the rigger seems to do it :  IF new.flag_indexation_required = 3 THEN  
       set new.flag_indexation_required = 0;
   ELSE
       set new.flag_indexation_required = 1;
   END IF;     Can you add your answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NEW` contains the values for all columns that the row will have after the update, not just the values you explicitly used in the update query.

To tell the trigger that you want to explicitly reset the value, you could use an otherwise unused (but valid) value to mark that information, and then act accordingly in the trigger, e.g., in your trigger, use (assuming signed tinyint)

```sql
IF new.flag = -1 THEN  
  set new.flag = 0;
ELSE
  set new.flag = 1;
END IF;
```

Then in your `update` query,

```sql
update table set flag = -1;
```

will set the value to `0`, any other value, or not using that column in your query at all, will set it to `1`.

There is an alternative and more common approach without triggers, that works similar to your flag. You can use a column

```sql
last_update datetime default null on update current_timestamp;
```

`null` in this column would have the same meaning as `flag = 0`, any other value would have the same meaning as `flag = 1`. They are set automatically. If you want to reset your "flag", you can simply use

```sql
update table set last_update = null;
```

Your trigger approach will of course work too perfectly fine. Just make sure to document that behaviour somewhere.